# Sample and paste a color from one object with a gradient to another object with a gradient

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have 2 images with the same object in them.  Both objects have a gradient.  I want to sample the color of the first object and paste it into the second object without destroying the gradient in the second object.

Choosing the eyedropper tool and sampling the color, then double-clicking on the fill-icon at the bottom of the tool panel, seems to work.  When the color-picker panel comes up, the numeric value of colors without a gradient is in that window.  But when I sample the color of the object with the gradient, the color-picker panel does not give me the correct numeric value of the color.

In all cases though, as soon as I sample the color of ANY object in the first image, the fill-icon changes to that color, with or without gradient.  Sampling the gradient color gives me that color, (with the gradient), in the fill-icon.  But when I double-click on the fill-icon, the gradient object color does not come up in the color-picker panel.  So I'll be unable to paste it into the second object.

Answer (score 1):

Place your colors in the Swatches Panel, then drag from swatches to your gradient.

You can't (as you've discovered) sample colors from one gradient to a different gradient. Sample the colors, make swatches, then move swatches to the new gradient.

Comment: No enough room 4 me 2 tell u everything!  I'm now trying to group the 3 parts of the first object so I can get the correct gradient in the second object.  The color transferred but the gradient was wrong.The gradient should cover all 3 parts of the object.

Comment: How do I explain the whole problem here?  I run of of characters!!!!

Comment: I'm gonna use "COMMENTS" but I donno if that's breaking the rules here.

Comment: I used the SWATCHES PANEL and the color transferred properly but the gradient did not.  I think that's because the gradient is supposed to cover all 3 parts of the object.  So I tried to group the 3 parts together.  A message came up saying "CAN'T GROUP OBJECTS THAT ARE PART OF DIFFERENT GROUPS".  So I tride to ungroup everything in the image but the UNGROUP command just inverted the colors.  Then after typing here a bit, I went back to Ai and the whole image seemed to be ungrouped.  So I chose the 3 parts of the object in question and tried to group them.

Comment: The same message came up.  "CAN'T GROUP OBJECTS THAT ARE PART OF OTHER GROUPS".

Comment: What do I do now?  :(

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/45334/how-do-i-apply-a-gradient-across-multiple-objects-in-illustrator