# How do I apply a gradient across multiple objects in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

I have two separate objects that I have applied gradient fill to.

The gradient fill seems to only apply to the objects as individuals. I tried grouping the shapes, but that doesn't seem to change the gradient.

[image]

**How do I get one gradient to cover all my shapes?**

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In order to get a single gradient to cover multiple objects, you need to use the **Gradient Tool**.

[image]

Select your objects, then with the **Gradient Tool**, click and drag from where you want the gradient to start, and let go where you want the gradient to end.

[image]

This will cause the gradient to cover *all* selected objects. You can then modify gradient settings using the **Gradient Panel**

Alternatively you can create a **Compound Shape** of the multiple objects, if feasible, and that will allow a gradient to see the compound shape as one object. However, Compound Shapes are not always a good solution for overall construction. It depends upon the artwork.

Comment: Great! Precise and to the point. I guess this only works from CS6 and after? Not sure.

Answer (score -4):

From http://www.bittbox.com/illustrator/illustrator-101-one-gradient-across-multiple-paths:

1. Select all of the objects you want to include
2. Object menu > Compound Object > Make (Cmd+8, Ctrl+8)
3. Apply your gradient to the gradient path.

Comment: I agree that this Answer has little to no merit on its face, but the cited article is spot-on and solved this problem for me, whereas the accepted answer (Scott's) did not. More specifically, Scott's answer looked promising, but when I select the Gradient tool, I cannot "click"; the cursor icon is a cross-hair with the crossed-out circle (AKA "no smoking sign"). The solution for me was to select all of the individual objects, right-click, and select "Make Compound Path", then apply the gradient.  Why I can't drag with the gradient tool, despite all layers being visible and unlocked... no idea.