# I want to apply to gradient for all selected same each shape all at once

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

[image]
I want to apply to gradient for all selected same each shape all at once it will result in each shape
how should I apply to gradient each shape which not combined one but do each one all at once?

I don't know the method, and I want to know it because of slower work time, however, if there isn't one, please tell me.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How do I apply a gradient across multiple objects in Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/45334/52050)

Comment: i have to move each shape gradient position

Comment: When I apply gradient function after selecting all the same shapes, only one part gets the gradient, so it takes a long time for me to finish one by one.

Comment: If you group objects, then apply 1 big gradient they all share that 1 big gradient, not many individual gradients. Does that help?

Comment: Nice Pineapple.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use the eyedropper tool in illustrator to apply one of the gradient to all. All you need to do is select the one you wanted to put as gradient Press I ( for eyedropper tool) and eyedrop the gradient color you already have. That should help :)[image]