# Making many objects one gradient

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

I tried everything.
I googled, found this site, tried everything:

[How do I apply a gradient across multiple objects in Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/45334/how-do-i-apply-a-gradient-across-multiple-objects-in-illustrator) 
 [image: The object with the groups]

[image: Trying to apply the gradient]

As you can see.. it doesn't work.
And I don't quite get why?
Any tips?
I tried to make it as clear as possible
Cheers
vic

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I tried and it works for me. Group objects, add gradient fill to group. Can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: What are you trying to apply the gradient to?  The strokes? Or are you trying to fill them with a gradient?

Answer (score 1):

You have to combine those shapes into a *compound path* before you apply the gradient. Just grouping them won't do it.

Comment: Kind of untrue. You *can* create a compound path certainly, but it's not mandatory.

Comment: @Scott I bow to your expertise with regards Illustrator. I still think the answer is likely to help the OP, but I am sure you can post a better answer.

Comment: Not really :) I don't understand why things aren't working in the first place, they should. So it comes down to construction issues.. which are impossible to discern :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay.. I'm going to make some **assumptions** here....

- You started with a pattern fill
- You expanded the pattern fill
- You are left with stroked paths, not filled shapes

---

If **expanding a pattern** which is comprised of strokes there are more steps which must be taken.....

So.. start with a pattern fill:

[image]

`Object > Expand Appearance` to expand the pattern.

Then using the **Direct Selection Tool** select and remove the outer clipping mask. This essentially leaves what *looks like* stroked paths.

[image]

**However**, there's *more under the hood*. Each pattern tile has *its own bounding shape (rectangle)*. Switch to **Outline Mode** (View > Outline) to see these rectangles.

[image]

[image]

Select and remove all the tile bounding rectangles.

[image]

*Now*, there are only stroked paths.

[image]

Onto the gradient fill.....

It is **not possible** to span gradients on strokes. Illustrator can't do that. Since the artwork is comprised of only stroked paths, it must be expanded to filled shapes. Select the artwork and choose `Object > Expand`. This converts the stroked paths to filled shapes.

[image]

It is possible to apply a gradient at this point. However, I prefer to **clean up** the artwork first. So, with the artwork selected, I would click the **Merge** button on the **Pathfinder Panel** converting all the various shapes to one (compound) shape.

[image]

Using the Merge operation of the Pathfinder panel often results in "hollow" objects. Objects which have *no fill or stroke* so they aren't seen, nonetheless they **are** there. A hint that this has happened is noted by the `Fill` on the **Color Panel**. The `?` indicates the selected objects have different fills. Looking at the selected artwork, it *should be* all one fill. So the color `?` means there are superfluous objects in the artwork.

- Whenever I use the Merge operation, I draw an *unfilled, unstroked rectangle* (anywhere). With this rectangle selected choose `Select > Same > Fill & Stroke` and hit the <kbd>DELETE</kbd> key to remove all these superfluous objects.

Finally, select the art and apply a gradient fill and adjust it to your liking with the **Gradient Tool**.

[image]

---

Your issue was probably 2 fold.. the expanded pattern resulting in unseen objects, then trying to span a gradient across strokes... which can't be done in Illustrator.

<sub>(CS6 screenshots, but it's all really the same in CC.)</sub>

Comment: That last image is *so* satisfying to look at.