# How to subtract a shape from another one grabbing gradient continuity?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, shapes, gradient, pathfinder

[image]

I wanna "cut" a triangle (see above, the black one) from that rectangle's left bottom corner, but when I use pathfinder or shape builder tools to do that, the triangle "assumes" the rectangle's full gradient, and instead, I need the triangle to "grab" gradient continuity, like if it had been cut with a scissor (on photoshop I just would have to rasterize the rectangle). I wanna put that triangle on my artwork left bottom, and sure, keeping it editable.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/45334/how-do-i-apply-a-gradient-across-multiple-objects-in-illustrator - Cut, select both, reapply the gradient.

Comment: I followed the instructions, I selected both shapes, made a compound path and applied the gradient. But, the problem is that when I get into the compound path isolation mode in order to position the triangle on my artwork left bottom, its gradient changes drastically, it gets a big distance from the gradient proportion the triangle gets when it's sticked on rectangle. See here > https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-doSGqfQg-KyOEECU476-yD-HeWADN8B/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Solved: in order to keep the gradient continuity and have the possibility of moving the shapes without changes on their gradient proportion, make a compound path and then apply a pathfinder "Divide". Bingo!