# Exporting a clipping mask object - Illustrator keeps the clipped object as transparent space

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I've looked all over the stack and internet but haven't been able to find the exact answer. I've tried doing the legacy "File > Export > Export As" and ticking "use artboard" but it hasn't solved my issue. I've also tried opening the SVG file and reducing the artboard to fit the content but as soon as I use it somewhere else, it just adds the transparent area back immediately.

I've attached my SVG and a snippet of the file. I have a lot of different objects on the illustrator file and don't want to break out to a new file everytime i want to export something. If anyone has any idea how to remove the transparent area from the clipping mask I'd really appreciate it.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pgtpr03xmjzg7uv/AAAUmFLfdOeJ2mp1N4O-bMYma?dl=0

Comment: Hi. It's not clear what your problem is.  Do you want a solid white background instead of a transparent one?  Are you trying to release the clipping mask? What format are you exporting as? Can you edit your question, and state exactly what you are trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: No, I have a layer mask using the text over the gradient background. When I export it, Illustrator has kept the area which the gradient takes up, but retailed it as a transparent area. If you open the SVG in Indesign or import it into something, you will see the issue.

Comment: I checked the files. I see no problems. There's only a gradient filled object with the letters used as a clipping mask. Why are you using InDesign to open/place an SVG? You could just use the AI file.  Also you still haven't said what format you are trying to export from Illustrator.

Comment: Why are you using a clipping mask in this manner? Simply apply the gradient to the **type shapes** rather than using them as a clipping mask ---  You *can* apply one gradient across all the shapes. [**see here**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/45334/how-do-i-apply-a-gradient-across-multiple-objects-in-illustrator/45335#45335) In AI, clipping masks **are** artwork and in many "export" cases the underlying artwork will *not* be ignored (even going from AI to PS). The only solution is to remove or expand the clipping mask, or find some other method of construction.

Comment: @scott, YES! haha, completely forgot about that. Sometimes it just takes a second pair of eyes to look at it! Solved

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to use a clipping mask in that manner.

Simply apply the gradient to the **type shapes** rather than using them as a clipping mask.

It's possible to apply one gradient across all the shapes. 
[See this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/45334/how-do-i-apply-a-gradient-across-multiple-objects-in-illustrator/45335#45335) if you are unfamiliar with how to do such a thing.

In Illustrator, clipping masks *are* artwork and in many "export" cases the underlying artwork will *not* be ignored. This is even true merely moving from Illustrator to Photoshop with artwork. If Photoshop can't "ignore" the dimensions of the underlying artwork, there's little hope it'll be ignored in the SVG format.

Often the only solution is to remove or expand the clipping mask, or find some alternate method of construction so that the underlying artwork doesn't extend farther than desired.

<sub>(I am a bit surprised that clipping to an artboard doesn't work, but that must be due to the vector nature of SVG files.)</sub>