# How do i apply a gradient to a bevelled letter S in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, gradient

I tried to add a gradient to a bevelled S but there are so many gradient line stuff to change it gets irritating. Is there a way I can just change it with one gradient setting line thing?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply **click-drag** with the **Gradient Tool**.

The numerous gradient annotators will be reduced to just one. There will then be *one* gradient which is spread across all selected objects.

See here: [How do I apply a gradient across multiple objects in Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/45334/how-do-i-apply-a-gradient-across-multiple-objects-in-illustrator)

Comment: Hahah thank you it worked!!